# attach href to anchor tag dynamically then invoke click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to generate `href` of `<a>` tag dynamically and then click event to download generate file.

Here is my code.

```
var bool = false;
$('#lnkDownloadPDF').click(function () {
    if (bool == false) {
        MakeAjaxRequest('POST', HomePageURL + 'DownloadPDFPath', '{"designID": "' + sessionStorage.getItem("designID") + '" }').done(function (result) {
            bool = true;
            $('#lnkDownloadPDF').attr('href', result.d);
            $('#lnkDownloadPDF').attr('download', 'sample.pdf');
            $('#lnkDownloadPDF').click();
        });
    }
});

<a id="lnkDownloadPDF" class="greenDownloadBtn" href="#">Download</a>
```

above code works but i have to click on link button twice to download the specified file.

Is there any better way to achieve the same ?

Comment: Is MakeAjaxRequest a function you created? I'm trying to make a fiddle but it seems like some parts are missing here.

Comment: when you had made an ajax call ,you have two options: 1: use window.open with the pdf link, and not try to invoke the click. 2:- after the first ajax call, make another ajax call with the url of the pdf with proper content encoding and handle the pdf contents in js to display .

Comment: @Yumecosmos Yes it is a custom function for making ajax calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call native DOM API click method:

```
$('#lnkDownloadPDF')[0].click();
```

Jquery explecitely disable it on click trigger for anchor.

Comment: @War10ck See the difference: https://jsfiddle.net/ncm7a3ty/1/  Now relevant jQuery source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#LC515